# SQL Server DataSet sync changes back to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a question that I would think would be easy, but I can't figure it out.

I'm working in Visual Studio 2012 with a typed DataSet that I generated from SQL Server. I added a column to one of the tables within Visual Studio (which there's an option for), and I can't figure out how to sync that change back to the server.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without customization, typed datasets cannot perform DDL modifications for you.  If you're starting a new project, I recommend looking into EntityFramework's "Code First" feature for this functionality.